# button javafx different styles

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a button change its style when you click on it, I could arrange myself to change from style1 to style2, now I can't figure it out to change it to a third style (style3). I used an if else statement, now I'm thinking of using Switch-case for a third one.

```
style = true;
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) ->
    {
    System.out.println("Hello!");
        if (style == true) {
    btn.getStyleClass().remove("button1");
    btn.getStyleClass().add("button2");
        }
        else {
    btn.getStyleClass().remove("button2");
    btn.getStyleClass().add("button1");
        }

        style=!style;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably dozens of ways to do this. Here is one:

```
private int currentStyle = 0 ;

private String[] styles = { "button1", "button2", "button3" };

// ...

btn.setOnAction(e -> {
    btn.getStyleClass().removeAll(styles);
    currentStyle = (currentStyle + 1) % styles.length ;
    btn.getStyleClass().add(styles[currentStyle]);
});
```